# Cronjob in cPanel can't find BeautifulSoup4 module

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, beautifulsoup, centos

I have a CentOS server on cPanel, on which I want to do some cronjobs and execute python3 scripts.

I import the code in the script as follows: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, but it says the script doesn't work with the message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'`.

I have installed BeautifulSoup4 from root (SSH) with `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`. And in server terminal I have checked bs4 that it actually exists with the following:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>hello world</p>', 'html.parser')
>>> print(soup)
<p>hello world</p>
>>> print(soup.text)
hello world
```

So BeautifulSoup does indeed work on the server, it's just that I don't know how to access it and make it available for my cronjob. The command I use there is:

```
/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python3 /home/my_server/scraping/testpython3.py
```

Should I install it in another way, use a virtual environment (venv), or something else?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try installing bs4 with:

```
/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: It looks like good a solution, but now I get `OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soupsieve-1.9.5.dist-info'`. Any idea how I can solve it? To put sudo before didn't work.